# Jade HTML from string formatting issues

Tags: html, node.js, express, formatting, pug

I am trying to render a piece of HTML (created by TinyMCE) which is stored in mongodb and later rendered by jade.

Here is my `post.content` string as it appears from a `console.log`:

```
<p>Well, I'll tell you about that...</p><p>Sometimes, we are just not sure about these things&nbsp;<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="1" style=""><strong>Until we get some formatting!!!!</strong></span></p>
```

I expect it to look like this:

> Well, I'll tell you about that...
>
> Sometimes, we are just not
>   sure about these things **Until we get some formatting!!!!**

And this is what I see (copied from chrome):

> ### What am I doing
>   here?
>
> ---
>
> <
>
> Well, I'll tell you about
>   that...
>
> Sometimes, we are just not sure about these
>   things **ï»¿Until we get some
>   formatting!!!!**
>
> >Well, I'll tell you
>   about that...
>
> Sometimes, we are just not sure about these
>   things **ï»¿Until we get some
>   formatting!!!!**
>
> >

This is the relevant section of my jade template:

```
.container.content
    h2 #{post.title}
    hr
    div
        #{post.content}
```

What am I doing wrong?

`ï»¿` apparently is the UTF-8 byte order mark...which points to a formatting problem, but I don't see anywhere where I either said anything about formatting or changed the formatting. It also doesn't make sense to show up in the middle of a thing. Nor does it cause problems with console.log. As for it repeating twice, I am quite befuddled. Perhaps I wrote my template wrong?

Comment: Can you try with `div!=post.content` or `!{post.content}` and see if you end up with the same problem?

Comment: You cannot see the BOM in your text editor, but it is there. Just delete the line and retype it yourself. If you have Notepad++ follow Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM to easily remove all BOM's

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried what [@Marcus Ekwall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358556/marcus-ekwall) said? Seems to work fine.

First your test data:

```
{
  post: [ {title: "<p>Well, I'll tell you about that...</p>", 
           content: '<p>Sometimes, we are just not sure about these things&nbsp;
                       <span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="1" style="">
                         <strong>Until we get some formatting!!!!</strong>
                       </span>
                     </p>'}]
}
```

Next the Jade markup:

```
.container.content
    h2 !{post[0].title}
    hr
    div 
      !{post[0].content}
```

At least the HTML output:

```
<div class="container content">
  <h2><p>Well, I'll tell you about that...</p></h2>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <p>
      Sometimes, we are just not sure about these things&nbsp;
      <span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="1" style="">
        <strong>Until we get some formatting!!!!</strong>
      </span>
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vfy23/).